# Eric5: The OK button of 'new project' dialog is disable

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, eric-ide

I have installed Eric5 successfully. But I could not create a new project, as the 'OK' button of the 'Project Properties' dialogue is disable.
Help !
Thank you very much.

PS: I install the dependence via synaptic. System is Ubuntu 14.04.

I have fund a indirect solution:

1. Download a example source, for example, from the tutorial of python: [tutorial of Eric4](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/tutorials/LogParser/chap4.html)
2. edit the *.e4p file with a text editor, make sure the value of 'version' of 'Project' section is 5.0 or higher.
3. Return Eric IDE, open the project.
4. Delete all the source files and save as the project file to a expect folder.
5. Add my source files and edit the project properties.
6. Save

Answer (score 5):

The OK button will be disabled if the project directory is the same with the work space directory.

Check this:

http://die-offenbachs.homelinux.org:48888/issues/issue126

Comment: Would be great if the dialog would indicate this.. still doesn't in eric7 23.2